# Manipulación de Diccionarios, incrementar valores repetidos en Python

Tags: python

Me encuentro realizando un ejercicio en donde me piden crear un menú dinámico:

- 1.- INGRESAR PRODUCTO
- 2.- MOSTRAR TOTAL VENTA
- 3.- LISTAR PRODUCTOS
- 4.- MOSTRAR PRODUCTO MÁS VENDIDO
- 5.- TERMINAR VENTA
- 6.- INGRESAR NUEVA VENTA
- 7.- SALIR

El problema que tengo es que el ejercicio me pide que en la opción 1 primero cree un diccionario con el nombre del producto, cantidad y precio para luego ingresar el dicc. a una lista, si el producto se repite debo incrementar la cantidad de ese mismo producto reemplazando el valor anterior sin repetir.

Aquí os muestro el código que llevo.

```
def agregar_producto(lista_productos, producto, cantidad, precio):
dicc_productos = {}
dicc_productos["producto"] = producto
dicc_productos["cantidad"] = cantidad
dicc_productos["precio"] = precio
lista_productos.append(dicc_productos)

def mostrar_lista_productos(lista_productos):
for i in lista_productos:
    print(f"-Producto: [{i['producto']}] -Cantidad: [{i['cantidad']}] -Precio: [${i['precio']}]")el código aquí

lista_productos = []

while True:
    print(f"-" * 40)
    print(f"""\t\t.: MENU :.
1.- INGRESAR PRODUCTO
2.- MOSTRAR TOTAL VENTA
3.- LISTAR PRODUCTOS
4.- MOSTRAR PRODUCTO MÁS VENDIDO
5.- TERMINAR VENTA
6.- INGRESAR NUEVA VENTA
7.- SALIR
""")
opc = int(input(f"Seleccione Opcion: "))
print(f"-" * 40)

if opc == 1:
    producto = input(f"Añadir Producto: ").title()
    cantidad = int(input(f"Añadir Cantidad: "))
    precio = int(input(f"Añadir Precio: "))
    agregar_producto(lista_productos, producto, cantidad, precio)

    print()
```

La opción 2 debe mostrar el total de la venta si es posible con una función para el cálculo.

He intentado con un par de métodos pero no logro dar con una solución en concreto.

Comment: Lo que yo recomendaría sería tener todo en un diccionario y al momento de mostrar los productos recién pasarlo a una lista. Esto serviría para saber mejor si un producto ya se encuentra en el diccionario. Si quieres mantener tu estructura actual solo debes recorrer la lista e ir buscando el producto e incrementar su valor en caso exista

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de nada me gustaría realizar algunas sugerencias sobre tu código. Es obvio que estás empezando y son mas que aceptables tanto los errores como la falta de experiencia, sin embargo, como profesional a día de hoy puedo decir que habría agradecido estos consejos cuando comenzaba, pues al final en el mundo profesional, es lo que se demanda.

Lo primero de nada, debes ser capaz de "imaginar" la lógica de cada parte por separado, ¡Sin abrumarse!, tan solo hay que descomponer el problema por trocitos y ver que, cada trocito es muy sencillo y toma su forma componiendo estos trocitos de problema.

Lo primero, antes de nada necesitas un bucle, algo que sea infinito y se repita **hasta el momento que tu desees**, esta última frase es importante, pues, te sugiero utilizar una variable booleana en lugar de directamente "While True", ayuda a su legibilidad y control del bucle según el caso.

```
is_required_new_opt = True
while is_required_new_opt:
    pass
```

Ahora pensemos como ordenador, guardo True en una variable con **nombre descriptivo**, algo que ayuda al mantenimiento del código, su lectura y entendimiento, facilita su trabajo.

Literalmente dice is_required_new_opt "es_requerida_nueva_opcion". Aquí como vemos cobra todo el sentido del mundo, nótese la importancia de dar un buen nombre a nuestras variables y que estas representen su verdadero propósito, facilita tu trabajo, progreso y evolución.

Ahora como ves, el bucle siempre dará vueltas hasta que "tu decidas" en un punto/ condición del bucle que quieras o desees cambiar esa variable a "False" porque (ya no requieres una nueva opción) y termina el while.

Ahora, queremos pintar un menú, como es estático y es un texto que no va a cambiar en cada vuelta, podemos dejarlo fuera, aparte en una variable "algo mas arriba/global" al "programa/scope" tal que así:

```
MENU_TEXT = f"""\t\t.: MENU :.
    1.- INGRESAR PRODUCTO
    2.- MOSTRAR TOTAL VENTA
    3.- LISTAR PRODUCTOS
    4.- MOSTRAR PRODUCTO MÁS VENDIDO
    5.- TERMINAR VENTA
    6.- INGRESAR NUEVA VENTA
    7.- SALIR
    """
```

Ahora, pintamos el menú en nuestro bucle

```
is_required_new_opt = True
while is_required_new_opt:
    print(MENU_TEXT)
```

Quitamos el "pass" que era solo para evitar que el código fallara y pudieramos definir la primera estructura del while sin nada dentro. Buena práctica utilizar el pass, ya que significa que vas haciendo cada trocito de forma independiente y pensando solo en esa parte que te concierne, antes de pasar al siguiente "problema".

Ahora añadimos la posibilidad de ingresar opciones para cada vuelta donde se pinte el menú. Además, es buena práctica realizar alguna comprobación en lugares donde pueda fallar y evitar que rompa el programa por un "mal uso" del usuario, como ingresar una opción incorrecta.

```
is_required_new_opt = True
while is_required_new_opt:
    print(MENU_TEXT)
    opt = int(input(f"Select option (1-7): "))
    if opt < 1 or opt > 7:
        print("Invalid menu option, please select valid option")
        continue
```

Quizás esto que voy a comentar ya es "excederme" para tu problema, pero, dado que esta respuesta está siendo un poco mas educativa, quiero puntualizar la buena práctica de evitar poner "números que no significan nada" o conocidos como "magic numbers", ese (1) de la primera opción y el (7) de la última opción, cuando hacemos la comprobación, en un código mas grande puede perder sentido o incluso el menú venir de base de datos, lo que nos lleva a no conocer que singifican esos números. Una buena práctica sería darles nombre de la siguiente forma:

```
MIN_OPT = 1
MAX_OPT = 7
is_required_new_opt = True
while is_required_new_opt:
    print(MENU_TEXT)
    opt = int(input(f"Select option (1-7): "))
    if opt < MIN_OPT or opt > MAX_OPT:
        print("Invalid menu option, please select valid option")
        continue
```

De nuevo, vemos como el "naming" y dar buen nombre al código y variables, hace mucho mas legible y con ello comprensible nuestro código de una pasada (finalidad para programar con eficiencia y calidad)

Ahora, por último nos queda la parte de las opciones, tan solo te voy a comentar el inicio y te dejaré acabar a ti, estoy seguro que con estos consejos serás mas que capáz de terminar, no solo esto programa, si no mucho mas y mas complejos ;)

Antes de probar nuestro programa, sugiero poner al menos la opción de salir para evitar que se quede en bucle infinito. Y con ello también aprovechamos para añadir la primera opción que vamos a comentar para finalizar la respuesta. Podemos reutilizar las variables para estas dos opciones.
A medida que crece el programa, puede cambiar en su expresión y necesidad de nombres o contexto, como es en este caso, ese "MIN_OPT" quizás ahora no tenga tanto sentido como "opción mínima" y sería quizás mas como "opción de ingresar producto". No vamos a cambiarlo dado que el programa es pequeño, no lo requiere, pero es interesante poner en relieve y destacar el valor que aporta un buen nombre a nuestras variables.

```
if opt == MIN_OPT:
    product_name = input(f"Añadir Producto: ").title()
    product_quantity = int(input(f"Añadir Cantidad: "))
    product_price = int(input(f"Añadir Precio: "))

elif opt == MAX_OPT:
    is_required_new_opt = False
```

Ahora, para trabajar la parte final de añadir productos, una vez mas debemos dividir el problema y pensaren cada trocito independiente (o parte del problema). Se comenta que, si el producto existe, debemos añadir mas cantidad a la que ya tenga, perfecto.

Entonces, como bien menciona @Christian en su comentario, sería mas interesante además de fácil utilizar un diccionario de la siguiente forma.

products_collection = {}

Cuando el programa llega aquí, lo que queremos es añadir en una nueva "clave" de diccionario con el nombre de ese producto de la siguiente forma. Solo en caso de ser nuevo producto, pedimos introducir cantidad y precio, ya que en otro caso (si ya existe) solo queremos actualizar la cantidad.

```
product_name = input(f"Añadir Producto: ").title()
if product_name in products_collection:
    products_collection[product_name][product_quantity] += int(input(f"Añadir MAS Cantidad: "))
else:
    products_collection[product_name] = {
        "cantidad": int(input(f"Añadir Cantidad inicial: ")),
        "precio": int(input(f"Añadir Precio: "))
    }
```

Quedando tu inicio de programa de la siguiente forma:

```
MENU_TEXT = f"""\t\t.: MENU :.
    1.- INGRESAR PRODUCTO
    2.- MOSTRAR TOTAL VENTA
    3.- LISTAR PRODUCTOS
    4.- MOSTRAR PRODUCTO MÁS VENDIDO
    5.- TERMINAR VENTA
    6.- INGRESAR NUEVA VENTA
    7.- SALIR
    """

MIN_OPT = 1
MAX_OPT = 7
is_required_new_opt = True

products_collection = {}
while is_required_new_opt:
    print(MENU_TEXT)
    opt = int(input(f"Select option (1-7): "))
    if opt < MIN_OPT or opt > MAX_OPT:
        print("Invalid menu option, please select valid option")
        continue

    if opt == MIN_OPT:
        product_name = input(f"Añadir Producto: ").title()
        if product_name in products_collection:
            products_collection[product_name]["cantidad"] += int(input(f"Añadir MAS Cantidad: "))
        else:
            products_collection[product_name] = {
                "cantidad": int(input(f"Añadir Cantidad inicial: ")),
                "precio": int(input(f"Añadir Precio: "))
            }
    elif opt == 3:
        print(products_collection)
    elif opt == MAX_OPT:
        is_required_new_opt = False
```

Por último, habrás notado que el código está en inglés. Recomendación, siempre hazlo en inglés. Si te dedicas al mundo del software, ingles es un MUST, al menos básico, por ello te animo a siempre programar el inglés que es el mejor estándar, ya que, puede ayudarte otra persona de forma mas "internacional" con cualquier proyecto o código que realices. (Es buena práctica y si algún día deseas trabajar en cualquier empresa mediana o grande van a demandar código en inglés siempre, consejo profesional)

Espero que a partir de aquí, todas estas "reglitas, consejos o simples comentarios" te llenen para inspirarte y crecer profesionalmente ;).

Recuerda valorar positivamente la respuesta para ayudar a otros en la comunidad a encontrar tanto soluciones como información que puede enriquecer.

Saludos!

Comment: Increíble @Minerill0, me abriste la mente la verdad me tome el tiempo de ir paso a paso para entender toda la lógica (que es lo que me costaba en el ejercicio) pero ahora en la forma que explicaste el problema y como ENSEÑASTE la solución me parece de lo mas hermoso, aun me falta mucha practica pero gracias a gente como tu, que brinda una manito a los novatos puedo seguir desarrollando el ejercicio sin problemas :)

Comment: Gracias a ti por ser parte de esta comunidad, y ánimo!, esa es la actitud!